# How to read chunks of data from a large file in R?

Tags: r, csv, large-files, skip, read.csv

I want to break a file without reading it all at once? Say I'm having 30000000 records. I want to have 30 files with 1000000 records each. Currently I'm using nrow and skip attribute in read.csv() but some ambiguous data is coming up.

```
fileConn1<-file("D:\\Vikas\\x1.csv", open = "a")
fileConn2<-file("D:\\Vikas\\x2.csv", open = "a")
fileConn3<-file("D:\\Vikas\\x3.csv", open = "a")
fileConn4<-file("D:\\Vikas\\x4.csv", open = "a")

df <- read.csv("abc.csv", skip = 200000,nrows = 100000)
counter <- 3

while(nrow(df)!=0){

colnames(df) <- c("X", "X_raw")
m <- 100000 * counter

temp1 <- df
temp1$X_raw <- gsub("\"","",temp1$X_raw)
temp1$X_raw <- as.character(temp1$X_raw)


for(i in 1:nrow(temp1)){

  test_data <- strsplit(temp1$X_raw[i], ",")
  if(length(test_data[[1]]) == 6){

    writeLines(temp1$X_raw[i], fileConn1)

  }else if(length(test_data[[1]]) == 12){

    writeLines(temp1$X_raw[i], fileConn2)

  }else if(length(test_data[[1]]) == 18){

    writeLines(temp1$X_raw[i], fileConn3)

  }else{

    writeLines(temp1$X_raw[i], fileConn4)

  }
}


df <- read.csv("abc.csv", skip = m,nrows = 100000)

counter <- counter + 1
}

close(fileConn1)
close(fileConn2)
close(fileConn3)
close(fileConn4)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should check out the `iotools` package. It has a `read.chunk` function that is pretty flexible and quite fast.

Comment: You should also check `data.table::fread` which is way faster

Comment: @emmanuel when I'm using fread I'm facing this error..
Internal error. No eol2 immediately before line 3 after sep detection.. Even if I'm skipping rows, I'm facing the same thing. tried with different sep values also, but same thing. Any guesses?

Comment: I guess it's because you have a missing "end of line" or a "end of line" that is followed by something. You should open a new question and provide a reproductible example.